# AJAX Render Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to accomplish what I think to be the most direct, though certainly not the most elegant, replication of a reddit style vote button. I have code that works without the AJAX, but I would like users to be able to click the vote buttons and they change appropriately without reloading the page (Hence the AJAX).

The problem occurs when I try to remove the vote button clicked on and replace with the appropriate 'highlighted' vote button. The reason I am replaceing the vote button is because I need to change it to a button that will unvote if clicked on.

(I have simplified this to just handle just upvoting since downvoting is the same mexhanic). Here is my **view**:

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.content %>
    <% if current_user.voted_as_when_voted_for post %>
      <%= render 'upvoted', post: post %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'upvote', post: post %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

The voted_as_when_voted_for method returns true if they have upvoted the post.
Here is the upvote and upvoted **forms**:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('upvoted.png', size: '18'), remove_like_post_path(post), method: :put, remote: true, id: "upvoted#{post.id}" %>

<%= link_to image_tag('upvote.png', size: '18'), like_post_path(post), method: :put, remote: true, id: "upvote#{post.id}" %>
```

**Here is my controller:**

```
def upvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.liked_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @post.parent }
    format.js   {}
  end
end

def remove_upvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.unliked_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @post.parent }
    format.js   {}
  end
end
```

**upvote.js.erb:** and **upvoted.js.erb:**

```
$('#upvote<%= @post.id %>').remove().append('<%= j render("upvoted") %>');

$('#upvoted<%= @post.id %>').remove().append('<%= j render("upvote") %>');
```

With those files I get the following console errors:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/96/like 500 (Internal Server Error) 

NameError in Posts#upvote

undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007fde1836cbf0>:0x007fde18c00af0>
```

**_upvote.html.erb** and **_upvoted.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to image_tag('upvote.png', size: '18'), like_post_path(post), method: :put, remote: true, id: "upvote#{post.id}" %>

<%= link_to image_tag('upvoted.png', size: '18'), like_post_path(post), method: :put, remote: true, id: "upvoted#{post.id}" %>
```

I also tried something like this based on the link below:

```
$('#upvote<%= @post.id %>').remove().after('<%= j render "upvoted", post: @post %>');
```

When I use that code, the upvote is succesfully removed, but the upvoted form is not added on. So it seems that I need to use the instance variable, but something is still not quite working.

What am I missing??

This person seemed to have a similar problem: [Rails Ajax Render Partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654021/rails-ajax-render-partial-voting-system)

Comment: Are there any errors in developer console? Are you able to alert inside your js.erb file?

Comment: I added in the console logs for the code that generates an error. I am new to rails and not very experienced with those logs so let me know if there is something more you wanted to see from them.

Comment: try $('#upvote<%= @post.id %>').remove().after('<%= j render partial: "upvoted", locals: {post: @post} %>');

Comment: There may be other issues here but as for the javascript, you are calling `.remove()` on the matched elements. Then trying to `append` to an element that is no longer there.

Comment: @veritas1, That is right, instead I appended first, then removed the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the real culprit to the ajax failing was using `.remove().after` My theory is that if I remove the element, then you can't add something after. So this fix solved the problem:

```
$('#upvote<%= @post.id %>').after('<%= j render "upvoted", post: @post %>');
$('#upvote<%= @post.id %>').remove();
```

Maybe not the most sophisticated, but it works! Note: I didn't want to use `.hide().after()` because I didn't want lots of hidden links lurking behind.

Answer (score 0):

**DRY**

Doesn't look very DRY to me

You could remove a lot of the duplicate code by making better use of your [HTTP Verbs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints) - by defining a `delete` route (for downvote) & `post` route (for upvote):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   match :vote, via: [:post, :delete] #-> domain.com/posts/14/vote
end

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
Class PostsController < ActiveRecord::Base
    respond_to :js, :html
    def vote
       @post = Post.find params[:id]

       if request.post? 
          @post.liked_by current_user
       elsif request.delete?
          @post.unliked_by current_user
       end

       respond_with @post
    end
end
```

**Views**

This will allow you to create the following JS & views:

```
#app/views/posts/vote.js.erb
$("<%= 'upvote##{@post.id}' %>").html('<%= j render "vote", locals: { post: @post } %>');
```

-

```
#app/views/posts/_vote.html.erb
image = current_user.voted_as_when_voted_for(post) ? "downvote.png" : "upvote.png"
method = current_user.voted_as_when_voted_for(post) ? :delete : :post

<%= link_to image_tag(image, size: '18'), post_vote_path(post), method: method, remote: true, id: "upvote#{post.id}" %>
```

-

```
#app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.content %>
    <%= render 'vote', post: post %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Fix**

After looking at your code, I would look at the error for hints as to what the issue might be:

> undefined local variable or method `post'

The problem seems to be called in your `upvote` action, which will have the `partial` `upvoted` like this:

```
$('#upvoted<%= @post.id %>').remove().append('<%= j render("upvote") %>');
```

The problem is this partial requires the `post` local variable. So the issue is that you're not passing the `@post` to your `partial` via the [`locals`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) argument

My code above addresses this, but in order to resolve it, you should just use `locals: { post: @post }`